# touch screen not working

Tags: power-supply, touchscreen

I just bought a touch screen ,First it Works fine, but after two weeks the screen and the LEDs blink, and if I connect my Pi 2 via HDMI, it doesn't work at all. I connect the USB of my PC to supply the PCB800099.
the Pi still boot correctly , no error messages ,if i supply the screen from the USB of my PC , it will be blue ( HDMI 'it looks fine ) but if i connect the HDMI of PI with HDMI of screen and i start my Raspi the screen blink (Black/white) and the LED blink too (red/green) every 1 sec ! help me please :(

### [image]

Answer (score 2):

Try providing power to the screen separately from the Pi.  As in, with a power supply plugged into the microUSB on the touchscreen controller board and NO jumper to the Pi board.  Two power supplies, one for the pi and one for the screen (and no +5v/gnd jumpers between the two).  If that works then you have a power supply problem with the one you've been using.

Comment: I solve it . It was a power supply problem , I use 12V/2A adapter

Comment: Yep, lots of power supplies used for Pi setups really don't have enough power when it comes to adding accessories onto the Pi.